# Android: How to implement page curling/flipping/turning effect in TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, page-curl, page-flipping

I have a TextView and I implemented two method for swipe right/left; And when I swipe, then the content changes.

And now I want to implement page turning effect when swiping in TextView.

How can I implement it?

Comment: you can put the `TextView` into a `ViewPager`

Comment: Can it be done with a TextView?